# Page Scrolls when advancing image slider on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code for this image slider.  When advancing to the next slide, the image scrolls to the top of the page every time.  I am aware that you can use "data-target" to prevent this but that just breaks the arrows.  What am I missing?
www.bird-supplies.net for reference.

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <span id="item-1"></span>
    <span id="item-2"></span>
    <span id="item-3"></span>
    <div class="carousel-item item-1">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-3"></a>
        <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item item-2">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-1"></a>
        <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-3"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item item-3">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-2"></a>
        <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-1"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I have a part two.  This slider code below does not anchor itself when proceeding to the next slide but it does not contain itself where I place it. It blows itself up to fill the whole screen. Probably a CSS issue.  If someone can help me contain this slider to where I have the first one then I'll just use this one and problem solved.

```
<div class="container">
<div data-am-fadeshow="next-prev-navigation autoplay">
<!-- Radio -->
<input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-1" />
<input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-2" />
<input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-3" />
<!-- Slides -->
<div class="fs-slides">
<div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: 
url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460500063983-994d4c27756c? 
crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb- 
0.3.5&q=80&w=2550);">
            <!-- Add content to images (sample) -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; 
transform: 
translate(-50%, -50%); color: white; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: 
center; text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <h1 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.8vw; font-size: 
5vw; font-weight: bold;">Pure CSS Fadeshow</h1>
                <p style="font-size: 2vw; font-weight: 100; margin-top: 
0;"> 
</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: 
url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440557653082-e8e186733eeb? 
crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb- 
0.3.5&q=80&w=2500);"> 
</div>
        <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: 
url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449057528837-7ca097b3520c? 
crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb- 
0.3.5&q=80&w=2500);"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Quick Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-quick-nav">
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Prev Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-prev-nav">
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Next Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-next-nav">
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

*CSS*

```
$max-slides:                    5;
$prefix:                        true;
$responsive:                    true;
$breakpoint-small:              500px;
$fade-time:                     1;
$prev-next-fontfamily:          sans-serif;
$prev-next-icon-size:           3vw;
$prev-next-icon-color:          rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
$prev-next-bg:                  rgba(255,255,255,0);
$prev-next-bg-hover:            rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
$prev-icon:                     '❮';
$next-icon:                     '❯';
$autohide-next-prev:            true;
$quick-nav-color:               rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
$quick-nav-active-color:    coral;
$fade-color:                    #fff;
$autoplay:                      true;
$autoplay-duration:         3;


/*
 * ===== MIXINS =====
/* Mixins to handle prefixes */

@mixin fadeshow-transition($value...) {
@if length($value) < 1 {
    $value: all 150ms linear;
}
@if $prefix == true {
    -webkit-transition: $value;
}
              transition: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-transform($value...) {
@if length($value) < 1 {
    $value: all 150ms linear;
}
@if $prefix == true {
    -webkit-transform: $value;
         -ms-transform: $value;
}
              transform: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-animation($value...) {
@if $prefix == true {
    -webkit-animation: $value;
}
              animation: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-animation-delay($value) {
@if $prefix == true {
    -webkit-animation-delay: $value;
}
              animation-delay: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-unselectable() {
@if $prefix == true {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
         -ms-user-select: none;
}
              user-select: none;
}

/* Mixins to handle Quick Navigation Button states */

@mixin quickNavBtnActive() {
background-color: $quick-nav-active-color;
}

@mixin quickNavBtnInactive() {
background-color: $quick-nav-color;
}


 /*
 * ===== FADESHOW =====
 *
 * Base functionality for the fadeshow.

[data-am-fadeshow] {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: $fade-color;

/* Slides */
.fs-slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    @include fadeshow-transition(opacity #{$fade-time}s ease);

    /* Display first child on load */
    &:first-child {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Quick Navigation */
.fs-quick-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    @include fadeshow-unselectable();
    @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(-50%));
}

.fs-quick-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    @include fadeshow-transition(opacity 200ms ease);
    @include quickNavBtnInactive();

    &:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    /* Set active state to first button on load */
    &:first-child {
        @include quickNavBtnActive();
    }
}

/* Prev/Next Navigation */
%prev-next {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: $prev-next-fontfamily;
    background-color: $prev-next-bg;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    @include fadeshow-transition(all 200ms ease);

    @if $responsive == true {
        @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }

    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        font-size: $prev-next-icon-size;
        color: $prev-next-icon-color;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: $prev-next-bg-hover;
        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
            }
        }
    }
}

.fs-prev-btn {
    @extend %prev-next;
    left: 0;

    &:before {
        content: "#{$prev-icon}";
        left: 50%;
        @include fadeshow-transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                left: 30px;
            }
        }
    }

    @if $autohide-next-prev == true {
        @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(-100%));
        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                @include fadeshow-transform(translate(0));
            }
        }
    }
}

.fs-next-btn {
    @extend %prev-next;
    right: 0;

    &:before {
        content: "#{$next-icon}";
        right: 50%;
        @include fadeshow-transform(translate(50%, -50%));
        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                right: 30px;
            }
        }
    }

    @if $autohide-next-prev == true {
        @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(100%));
        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                @include fadeshow-transform(translate(0));
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Base functionality */
input[type="radio"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: -9999px;

    &:checked {

        /* This loop handles the slide switching and quick navigation 
active state */
        $i: $max-slides;

        @while $i > 0 {

            &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
                /* Show slide */
                ~ .fs-slides {
                    .fs-slide {
                        //Cancel autoplay
                        opacity: 0;
                        @include fadeshow-animation(none !important);
                    }
                    .fs-slide:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                }

                /* Add active state to dot */
                ~ .fs-quick-nav {
                    .fs-quick-btn {
                        @include quickNavBtnInactive();
                        /* Cancel autoplay */
                        @include fadeshow-animation(none !important);
                    }
                    .fs-quick-btn:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                        background-color: $quick-nav-active-color;
                        &:hover {
                            opacity: 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            $i: $i - 1;
        }

        /* Hide navigation if only one slide */
        &:first-of-type:last-of-type {
            ~ .fs-quick-nav,
            ~ .fs-prev-nav,
            ~ .fs-next-nav {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

    }
}

/* Autohide Prev/Next Navigation */
@if $autohide-next-prev == true {
    &:hover {
        .fs-prev-btn,
        .fs-next-btn {
            @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(0));
        }
    }
}

}


/*
 * ===== PREV/NEXT NAVIGATION =====
 *
 * This section handles the prev/next navigation.
 */

/* Handle Prev/Next buttons */
[data-am-fadeshow~="next-prev-navigation"] {
input[type="radio"] {

    &:checked {

        $i: $max-slides;

        @while $i > 0 {

            &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {

                $prev: ($i - 1);
                $next: ($i + 1);

                /* Show previous button */
                @if $prev > 0 {
                    ~ .fs-prev-nav {
                        .fs-prev-btn {
                            display: none;
                        }
                        .fs-prev-btn:nth-child(#{$prev}) {
                            display: block;
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Show next button */
                @if $next < ($max-slides + 1) {
                    ~ .fs-next-nav {
                        .fs-next-btn {
                            display: none;
                        }
                        .fs-next-btn:nth-child(#{$next}) {
                            display: block;
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Show last prev button if first slide */
                &:first-of-type {
                    ~ .fs-prev-nav {
                        .fs-prev-btn:last-child {
                            display: block;
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Show first next button if last slide */
                &:last-of-type {
                    ~ .fs-next-nav {
                        .fs-next-btn:first-child {
                            display: block;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
          $i: $i - 1;
        }
    }
}

/* Display first pair of Prev/Next Buttons on load */
.fs-prev-btn:last-child {
    display: block;
}

.fs-next-btn:nth-child(2) {
    display: block
}

}


/*
 * ===== AUTOPLAY =====
 *
 * Functions to handle autoplay.

@if $autoplay == true {

$i: $max-slides;

@while $i > 1 {

    $total-duration: $autoplay-duration * $i;

    @keyframes quickNavAnimation-#{$i} {
        0% { @include quickNavBtnInactive();  }
        #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
        #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { @include 
quickNavBtnActive(); }
        #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
        100% { @include quickNavBtnInactive(); }
    }
    @if $prefix == true {
        @-webkit-keyframes quickNavAnimation-#{$i} {
            0% { @include quickNavBtnInactive();  }
            #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
            #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { @include 
quickNavBtnActive(); }
            #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
            100% { @include quickNavBtnInactive(); }
        }
    }

    @keyframes slidesAnimation-#{$i} {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
        #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { opacity: 1; }
        #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
        100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
    @if $prefix == true {
        @-webkit-keyframes slidesAnimation-#{$i} {
            0% { opacity: 0; }
            #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
            #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { opacity: 1; }
            #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
            100% { opacity: 0; }
        }
    }

    [data-am-fadeshow~="autoplay"] {
        input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(#{$i}):last-of-type {

            /* Slide animation */
            ~ .fs-slides {
                .fs-slide {
                    @include fadeshow-animation(slidesAnimation-#{$i} # 
{$total-duration}s infinite);
                }
            }

            /* Quick navigation animation */
            ~ .fs-quick-nav {
                .fs-quick-btn {
                    @include fadeshow-animation(quickNavAnimation-#{$i} # 
{$total-duration}s infinite);
                }
            }

            /* Animation Delay */
            @for $j from 1 through $i {
                ~ .fs-slides .fs-slide:nth-child(#{$j}),
                ~ .fs-quick-nav .fs-quick-btn:nth-child(#{$j}) {
                    $animation-delay: #{($j - 1) * ($autoplay-duration) - 
$fade-time}s;
                    @include fadeshow-animation-delay(#{$animation- 
delay});
                }
            }

        }
        $i: $i - 1;
    }
}
}

/* Base Styling */

body {
margin: 0;
}

.container {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Probably simply the effect of the anchor links doing their normal job … so prevent the click event default action for those links in your JavaScript …?

Answer (score 0):

This javascript code should prevent the scroll.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on( "click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Not sure if it will make problem with slider. Please let me know.

Comment: hmm for some reason that made the slider ignore all of its size properties.  It blew up to cover the whole page

Comment: I tried adding that script in the Body of the page as well as where the slider actually resides.  In the body the slider blows up, in the area where the page resides the slider disappears completely.  I'm using netsuite.  If you are familiar then you know there are several places to input code which makes it even more confusing

Comment: disregard my first comment. I forgot to include the script tag. not enough coffee... its not affecting the slider size anymore but yeah its still scrolling.  that code isn't working.

Comment: This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006289/bootstrap-carousel-jumps-to-top-of-page-when-advancing

Comment: Or, may be this code:
`<script type="text/javascript">$('.carousel-control').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});</script>`.
write the code after the `html` code of slider.

Comment: and i started with that first thread you just linked.  thats where I got the info to try data-target.  I am suspect to believe that it might be something to do with how netsuite reads js.  maybe in the field I am entering it, you can't put js code.  I feel like any one of these solutions should have worked. I am also curious why the second one I posted in my edit doesn't seem to have this problem